# How to receive text from Server to Client in Indy 10 TCP/IP in Delphi 7?

Tags: delphi, tcp, timer, indy10

I am working on a chat application with Indy 10 in Delphi 7. Now, on the client side, Indy does not have an `OnDataReceived` or `OnRead` event, so how can I receive text from the server to the client?

I did try to use the `OnWork` event with a timer, but my timer is not woking.

Here are the codes for `OnWork` and `TTimer` that I used:

```
procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if zb_FDataReceived then
  begin
    ShowMessage('Timer triggered!');
    ClientOutput.Lines.Add('Server: ' + zb_FReceivedData);
    zb_FDataReceived := False;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.IdTime1Work(ASender: TObject; AWorkMode: TWorkMode;
  AWorkCount: Integer);
begin
  if zb_FDataReceived then
  begin
    ShowMessage('Timer triggered!');
    ClientOutput .Lines.Add('Server: ' + zb_FReceivedData);
    zb_FDataReceived := False;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Where and how is `zb_FDataReceived` set? It's missing in the your code example. Also why would you output `'Timer triggered!'` when `TForm1.IdTime1Work()` cannot be a timer event? If it should execute the same code then you should just call `self.Timer1Timer( ASender );`.

Answer (score 5):

Most Indy clients operate *synchronously*, which is why there is no event in `TIdTCPClient` when incoming data arrives. The client doesn't read data from the socket until you tell it to read.  The `OnWork` events are meant to be used for status reporting *while* you are reading/writing data, ie to update a progress bar, etc.

So, to do what you are attempting, you *can* use a timer, but not in the way you are trying to. On each timer event, you would need to query the socket with a short timeout to see if it has data waiting, and if so then read it. For example:

```
procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if Client.IOHandler.InputBufferIsEmpty then
  begin
    Client.IOHandler.CheckForDataOnSource(0);
    Client.IOHandler.CheckForDisconnect;
    if Client.IOHandler.InputBufferIsEmpty then Exit;
  end;
  // read a message from the Client as needed...
end;
```

That being said, it is usually best to use a separate thread rather than a timer. Have the thread run a loop where each iteration reads from the socket until a new message arrives and then notifies the Main UI thread to display the message. For example:

```
type
  TReadingThread = class(TThread)
  protected
    FClient: TIdTCPClient;
    procedure Execute; override;
  public
    constructor Create(AClient: TIdTCPClient);
  end;

constructor Create(AClient: TIdTCPClient);
begin
  inherited Create(False);
  FClient := AClient;
end;

procedure TReadingThread.Execute;
begin
  while (not Terminated) and FClient.Connected do
  begin
    // read a message from FClient as needed...
    // update main UI as needed ...
  end;
end;
```

```
Client.Connect;
RThread := TReadingThread.Create(Client);
...
Client.Disconnect;
RThread.Terminate;
RThread.WaitFor;
RThread.Free;
```